# Youtube v3 API commentThreads' searchterm does not seem to work

Tags: youtube-api

Has anybody managed to use 'searchTerms' in the commentThreads API from youtube?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#searchTerms

a working example would be greatly appreciated, everything I've tried does not seem to work

Example none working API call: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key={{myKeyHere}}&textFormat=html&part=snippet&videoId=KUOhpQDDME4&searchTerms=you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Your example is working for me, I have a responce with "you" word in comments.
Anyway, try to use one more parameter - "order", it has cured my request.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key={{myKeyHere}}&textFormat=html&part=snippet&videoId=KUOhpQDDME4&searchTerms=you**&order=time**